# How to compare Obj C enum in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using FreeStreamer in Swift and am trying to set the `onStateChange` block.

```
audioStream.onStateChange = { (state) in
    if state == kFsAudioStreamBuffering {
        //blah
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(FSAudioStreamState)' and 'FSAudioStreamState'
```

Edit: Still the same error without the parentheses around state in the block params

EDIT: As a temporary fix, `state.value == kFsAudioStreamBuffering.value` works

Comment: Can you remove the parenthesis from `(state)`?

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting a dot (.) before `kFsAudioStreamBuffering`
something like this:

```
if state == .kFsAudioStreamBuffering {
    //blah
}
```

UPDATE: Try this instead

```
audioStream.onStateChange = { state in
    if state.value == kFsAudioStreamBuffering.value {
        //blah
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work. `Could not find member 'kFsAudioStreamBuffering'`

Comment: The idea is correct but it will probably be only `.Buffering`.

Comment: Yes, @Sulthan that could be it, mergesort in swift, some enum values have theirs name shortened. try putting the name of the enum in swift then (dot) and you will be able to see it's new value name

Comment: Oh, it's a simple "enum", it's not "NS_ENUM". That's why the name is not shortened and why using ".value" is needed.

Comment: yes, I was looking to that right now, at https://github.com/clsource/radiouvm-ios/blob/master/RadioUVM/Pods/FreeStreamer/Common/FSAudioStream.h

Comment: @Sulthan I'm trying to download the project to update the answer with the exact and tested response. If you did it already, please do not hesitate on editing or giving your own answer.

Comment: I already updated my answer with a solution that do not let the compiler make any complaints.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this to make it work.

```
    self.audioControler?.onStateChange = { (state:FSAudioStreamState) -> Void in
        switch state {
        case .fsAudioStreamRetrievingURL:
```